# Error 1064 for invalid syntax keeps showing,and im not sure why

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, xampp

In my hyper terminal every time I run my node server,and go to / on localhost:3000 i get error 1064 indicating that my sql syntax is invalid,

```
let name='SEAD MAJDANČIĆ';
let sql='SELECT name FROM tblpolisa WHERE name='+name;
```

and i constantly get error 1064,i tried many options online,but this one was my original,the one i wrote first...others included all kinds of stuff but everytime same 1064 syntax error

Comment: `let sql='SELECT name FROM tblpolisa WHERE name like ' + name;`

Comment: You must wrap the value to bу searched for into quote chars: `let sql="SELECT name FROM tblpolisa WHERE name='"+name+"'";` If `name` itself contains quote chars `'` they must be quoted as `\'`.

Comment: @Akina doesnt seem to work as well,still 1064 error

Comment: Learn to use paramerters!

Comment: Show the value obtained in `sql` variable.